# How can I get the input of a button on a website using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm  a bloody beginner at this,so please don't judge me,ok?
So I made a Website with this text field:

```
Text: <input type="text" name="text" value="" id="input1"/>
```

And I made a button,used to get the input of the Text field:

```
<input type="submit" onclick=getinput>
```

and this is the getinput()-function:

```
<script>
   function getinput(){
     const val = document.querySelector('input1').value;
     console.log(val);
     console.log("No error in function implement.");
   }
</script>
```

but I generated the following error:

```
VM195:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at <anonymous>:3:45
```

I don't know what this error means,and how to fix it,could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some small mistake / bugs in your code. i refeactor it.

1.) the querySelector was wrong. For Ids use '#slectorName'.

2.) `onclick="getinput()"` instead `onclick=getinput`

```js
function getinput(){
    const val = document.querySelector('#input1').value;
    console.log(val);
    console.log("No error in function implement.");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="text" value="" id="input1"/>

<input type="submit" onclick="getinput()">
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the selector. To select an id with document.querySelector, you have to prefix it with a hashtag. Like:

```js
function getinput(){
  const val = document.querySelector('#input1').value;
  console.log(val);
  console.log("No error in function implement.");
}
```

Alternatively, you can use document.getElementById. For example:

```js
function getinput(){
  const val = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  console.log(val);
  console.log("No error in function implement.");
}
```

Also, in the submit button, you have to wrap the attribute value in double quotes. You have to write this:

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="getinput()">
```

instead of this:

```html
<input type="submit" onclick=getinput>
```